# xstate-how to return from data from interpret(machine).onDone()

Tags: xstate

I want to return data from onDone(). I have tried reply() function, but it is also not working.

```
server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/change-state/testing',
        handler:  function (request,h) {
             return interpret(machine)
             .onDone(e => {
               console.log('_____________________')
               console.log(e.data)
               console.log('_____________________')
                 return e.data // I want to return e.data
             })
            .start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that using an action:

```
export const machineDefinition = {
  id: 'loginForm',
  initial: 'idle',
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        PROCESS: [
          {
            cond: 'dataIsValid',
            actions: [ 'cleanErrorOnInputs' ],
            target: 'processing',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    processing: {
      entry: [ 'disableAll' ],
      invoke: [
        {
          id: 'signIn',
          src: 'signIn',
          onDone: {
            actions: [ 'sendDataToParent' ],
            target: 'finished',
          },
          onError: {
            actions: [ 'saveError' ],
            target: 'failed',
          },
        },
      ],
      exit: [ 'enableAll' ],
    },
    finished: {
      on: {
        PROCESS: {
          target: 'processing',
        },
      },
    },
    failed: {
      after: {
        1: {
          target: 'idle',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and the action looks like this:

```
const machineOptions = {
  actions: {
    sendDataToParent: sendParent((context, event) => ({ type: 'SAVE_SESSION', data: event.data })),
  },
};
```

So, in that way, I save the data in the context.

If is not enough clear, you can check [this boilerplate](https://gitlab.com/disruptivo.io/internals/frontend/react-starter-kit)